# Good Reference Book

Tags: pstricks, graphs, tutorials

I am having a problem getting two sets of data plotted on the same graph and have trawled the www for info on how to solve it.  The closest I have found is [this TeX.SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80062).
However, that is a specific solution to a specific question.

My question is, therefore, "can anyone recommend a good reference on how to get PS tricks to do what you want?".  I have bought a copy of "PS Tricks" by Herbert Voß; this gives a lot (!) of examples of what can be achieved and the code to achieve it - and it gives some (but not much) explanation on how the parameters are chosen.  I have also found (various copies of) "`ps-plot.pdf`" which gives lists of what the parameters are and what they are intended to do - but its examples are not particularly clear/useful.

I need/want something which works the other way to Voß's book; i.e. it gives good, clear explanations of the parameters and options, and then gives examples on how changing the parameters affects the output (rather than just moving on to the next example).

Comment: So, in fact you are looking for an introduction, rather than a complete reference?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Are you bound to PS Tricks? As you are talking about plotting data, I personally recommend http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots as it is quite easy and has an introduction/reference as what you are looking for. Just in case you didn't know this... can't help with pstricks

Comment: Good point, @LaRiFaRi. There is also the relatively new [pgfplots.net](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/) with examples.

Comment: The documentation of the package [`pgfplots`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) and my question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151909/) give an impression you what you are looking for if this is the way you want to go... `pgfplots` is a package based on the package [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) which is similar in usage as psplots.

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I'm using the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package for this task quite often. Do you have some working example of yours or a sketch we could start playing with?

Comment: Johannes_B: It depends on what you mean by 'introduction' - I am not looking for something which tells me (for example) what I need to set to get the tick marks on the y-axis to appear 0 0.0025 0.0050 0.0075 0.0100 0.0125 and 0.0150 (i.e. invervals of 1/400 from 0 to 6/400). I don't think I need a basic manual which tells me how (for example) to change line color.

Comment: LaRiFaRi: No, I'm not bound to anything. Excel plots the graphs correctly, but I am having a nightmare getting the correct aspect ratio into LaTeX. I have tried R, but the fonts are abysmal. I am willing to try anything - altho last time I tried Tikz I has to reinstall all LaTeX, so pgfplots may not be usable.

Comment: Malipivo: Sorry, I don't have an example on this machine - I can submit one here tonight (depending on geographical location) which will be about 8 hours.

Comment: General: I have just realised that those 3 comments are all in the same place - please could someone give mne the url for instructions to add comments into the relevane point in the conversation.

Comment: So you look for a reference, which is not a reference because it should contain very verbose examples of any parameter... Quite ambitious. It would be easier to help you with a concrete example and the problems you're having with it. About the general part: Comments aren't thought for extended conversations, use the chat for this. You can notify a user with e.g. @MarkTucker.

Comment: I am looking for a reference like O'Reilly Nutshell. Good, clear, and comprehensive. If you solve this problem, how do I know which parameters to change for the next graph?

Comment: I suggest [learning by example](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples).

Answer (score 3):

run from the terminal `texdoc pst-plot` or if you do not know how to run such a command http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/doc/pst-plot-doc.pdf

and for examples view http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/pstplot or the documentation from TUG.india: http://tug.org/PSTricks/doc/sarovar/chap7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have found the perfect solution; "Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis" (2009 Edition) by Hadley Wickham

Clearly, that's not LaTeX, but it is a book at the level someone (or a collection of experts) should write - and then advertise on this forum.